# How to change firefox Location setting

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, browser

I want to Change our Browser location to usa Please help me changing firefox location i.e geolocation location for testing.

Comment: Oh like trick your geolocation api to think its coming from China when you're actually in Australia?

Comment: Yes Right i am looking for trick...

Answer (score 9):

The two preferences mentioned by nmaler are spot-on. Additionally, you don't need a (local) server, a data:-URI works fine too.

For example, if you set the preference `geo.wifi.uri` (at `about:config`) with value:

```js
data:,{"location":{"lat":1.2,"lng":3.4},"accuracy":4000}
```

and then test by running the following from the JS console:

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => console.log(pos.coords));
```

then you will see that the spoof succeeded:

```js
Coordinates { latitude: 1.3, longitude: 11, altitude: 0, accuracy: 4000, ... }
```

If you need to generate a valid data:-URL with JavaScript (e.g. in add-on code), use the following. Note that I use `encodeURIComponent` just in case the `pos` object somehow contains special characters such as `%` or `#` (this is unlikely, but better safe than sorry):

```js
var pos = {
    location: {
        lat: 1.2,
        lng: 3.4,
    },
    accuracy: 4000,
};
var geoWifiUrl = `data:,${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(pos))}`;
// TODO: Set geo.wifi.url's pref to geoWifiUrl.
```

Comment: If you are on macOS, you also need to set `geo.provider.use_corelocation` to `false` and restart Firefox. (`geo.provider.use_corelocation` takes precedence over `geo.wifi.uri`.) Also, `geo.provider.testing` doesn't seem to be required, at least on Firefox 66.

Comment: This solution is not working currently, even the other solution that worked previously by changing `geo.provider.network.url` to a value like `data:application/json,{"location": {"lat": 40.7590, "lng": -73.9845}, "accuracy": 27000.0}` (https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/disable-fake-location-firefox-internet-explorer-chrome/). However the Firefox addon Location Guard still works.
Update: it works by setting `geo.provider.testing` to `true` like in nmaier's answer! (necessary on Linux Firefox 104 64-bit from Mozilla website at least @smammy)

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way would be to setup your own geolocation mock server and change some preferences:

1. Create (or change) the boolean `geo.provider.testing`, setting it to `true`. This will force the network provider on (instead of an OS level geo location provider, if any).
2. Change the `geo.wifi.uri` to the URI of your mock server, e.g. `http://localhost:8888/`
3. Start your mock server and restart Firefox.
4. Test that stuff works, [e.g.](http://html5demos.com/geo)

You can change preferences in `about:config` or by editing the `prefs.js` file of your browser profile directly. Easiest way to open the profile directory is using the corresponding button in `about:support`.

Sample mock server in python2 (returning always the coordinates for the White House):

```
import json
import BaseHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8888
LAT, LNG = 38.894967, -77.034917


class GeoHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({
            "location": {
                "lat": LAT,
                "lng": LNG
            },
            "accuracy": 4000
            }))

    def do_POST(self):
        return self.do_GET()

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), GeoHandler)
print "serving at port
```

Comment: @Blagoh OP wanted "Change our Browser location to usa". What is more "USA" than the White House? The WalMart or MacDownloads or CocaCola HQs maybe :p

Comment: I was posting to agree with McDonalads and then on second pass I realized the spelling... ROFL

Comment: @Blagoh Damn... That's what you get for seeing that crappy MacBook line in front of you all day. :P

Comment: I'm Windoze 7.0!! (No witty spelling on MacBook? :P)

Comment: This is fantastic. We need to find a pure javascript way to do this, I recommended this add-on use this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/location-guard/

Comment: Hey @nmaier I just made an addon out of this - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fake-location/ - super basic, someone on reddit requested something like it - https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/59ucfh/how_can_i_set_fake_my_geolocation_in_firefox/ - I used a server, as I couldn't figure out how to do it with pure js :(

Comment: Python 2 is deprecated and I was not able to run the script (there seems to be a quote missing after the print also). But thanks for mentioning to set `geo.provider.testing` to `true`, we can simply run a web server like Apache and return the same data. Or even better without server by changing `geo.provider.network.url` to a value like `data:application/json,{"location": {"lat": 40.7590, "lng": -73.9845}, "accuracy": 27000.0}` (https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/disable-fake-location-firefox-internet-explorer-chrome/) cc @Noitidart.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to spoof your location for the [HTML5 Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) you can follow these steps:

- Go to `about:config`.
- Type in `geo.wifi.uri`.
- Change the value to something like this:

  ```
  data:application/json,{"location": {"lat": 40.7590, "lng": -73.9845}, "accuracy": 27000.0}
  ```

  (The `lat` and `lng` values determine the latitude and longitude of your location.)
- Congratulations, you're now on Times Square! (You can test the result [here](http://html5demos.com/geo).)

Note that if you want to prevent websites from deriving the location from your IP address you can't do that on the application layer - the only way will be a proxy.

Comment: I've tested this.  It works!! Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

By opening `about:config`, we can spoof geolocation by changing `geo.provider.network.url` to a value like `data:application/json,{"location": {"lat": 40.7590, "lng": -73.9845}, "accuracy": 27000.0}` which is explained on https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/disable-fake-location-firefox-internet-explorer-chrome/.

No server or addon is needed but like mentioned in the answer of nmaier, I also had to set `geo.provider.testing` to `true` and restart Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is reading a JSON.

To make it work from a local server URL, we have to set the header to `Content-Type: application/json`. The browser will then read the location data accordingly.

Base example using PHP.

```
<?php
  $lon = 50.5123; // Location longitude
  $lat = 3.6525;  // Location latitude
  header('Content-Type: application/json'); // JSON header
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); // CORS request allowed
  echo json_encode((object)['location'=>['lat' => $lon, 'lng' => $lat], 'accuracy' => 1000]); // Data
```

Now serve this file:

```
php -S localhost:9999 myFakeGPS.php
```

Provide the URL `http://localhost:9999/` to the browser via `about:config`, in either `geo.provider.network.url`, or `geo.wifi.uri`.

This is **powerful to develop GPS/Routing apps.**

Answer (score 0):

To change your broswer's geolocation, you can download the [open-source](https://github.com/chatziko/location-guard/#what-is-a-fixed-location) add-on **Location Guard** and follow these steps:

0. Download it from [**here**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/location-guard/).
1. After installation, skip the add-on's demo and go into its options.
2. Change the `Default level` in its settings from `Medium` to `Use fixed location` from the drop-down.
3. Set any location of your choice in the Fixed Location tab.

Using this method you won't have to mess with `about:config` if you need websites to access your real location, since you can set different location using privacy levels (Low, Medium, High) for particular websites and a default location (or level here) for all the other websites. 
Although the Fixed location setting may be pretty inaccurate, by using it, websites don't even ask for permission to use your location. You can read more about this on the add-on's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/chatziko/location-guard/#what-is-a-fixed-location).

Keep in mind this does *not* affect your public IP in any way. After applying the settings you can check your IP Address Location and Browser Geolocation on https://mylocation.org/.