# How to fake Html5 GeoLocation API with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

In a firefox webExtension I want to select a country and use the json location to replace the `geo.wifi.uri` firefox config.

**choose_location.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="choose_location.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="../locations/default.png" alt="default" id="country_icon"/>
    <span id="location">Location</span>
    <select id="countries" class="country_select">
      <option value="default">Default</option>
      <option value="us">United States - Washington</option>
      <option value="ca">Canada - Ottawa</option>
    </select>    
    <div class="save">Save</div>    
    <script src="choose_location.js"></script>
  </body>    
</html>
```

**choose_location.js:**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // read geo.wifi.uri ???
});

// To display the correct flag when change the country location
document.getElementById('countries').addEventListener('change', function(){
    document.getElementById('country_icon').src = 'iso_code.png';
});

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("save")) {
        // Save, Replace or Bypass the new location ???
    }
});
```

I search on the doc and it's seems that is not possible to modify this kind of variable via javascript due to security purposes. I search an other way like modify directly the file, or replace on the fly on each page load, but without success. I know that I can change it manually, but I search a solution to do it programmatically.

**Edit:** I have override the [`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) method.

```
// Success callback
function success(position) {
    console.log('Success');
    console.log(position.coords.lat);
    console.log(position.coords.lng);
}    
// Error callback
function error(position) {
    console.log('Could not find you!');
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success, error){
    var customPosition = {};
    customPosition.coords = {};
    customPosition.coords.lat = 45.4111;
    customPosition.coords.lng = -75.6981;
    success(customPosition); // Ottawa
}
```

When I call the method manually, the callback is called but when I test on [Html5 geo API test](https://bestvpn.org/html5demos/geo/) it doesn't work.

**Edit 2:** As Titus said, in the manifest I put the `"run_at": "document_start"` value in the `"content_scripts"` section and I try two things:

- Simple script execution: It's override the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` method but it's working only in the script context
- Code injection in the page

  - With `"document_start"`: Too early, the injection does nothing
  - With `"document_end"`: The injection works but the authorisation is asked before the overriding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change firefox Location setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932199/how-to-change-firefox-location-setting)

Comment: I don't think that you can change `geo.wifi.uri` from an extension. What you could do instead is to inject a content script in every page and have this content script override `navigator.geolocation`.

Comment: @Titus, I have try to override `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` in the javascript console. When I use it manually, it return my fake position but when I test on this [website](https://bestvpn.org/html5demos/geo/) it doesn't work.

Comment: You'll need to set the [run_at](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts#run_at) option to `document_start` so that your content script will run before all other scripts.

Comment: You may want to keep a reference to the original `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` function so you can call it so the user will see the permission request notification. [`navigator.geolocation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation) has other methods beside `getCurrentPosition`, you should override those as well.

Comment: @Titus, I have update the result in my question

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you don't need any DOM nodes in order to override that function, all you'll need is a content script that contains the code in your question and is set to `"runt_at": "document_start"`. You've mentioned injecting javascript into the page, you need to use the [`js`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts#js) option instead of injecting the code using the `executeScript` function.

Comment: @Titus, Yes, `"run_at": "document_start"` is executed before the call of the getCurrentPosition() in the page, but it's works only if I execute the method from my script, if the page call it, it is the originial object.

Comment: I think that is because the context is different, try `window.top.navigator.geolocation. getCurrentPosition = ....`. If that doesn't work, try to inject a `<script>` element with this code into the document, something like `document.head.appendChild(scriptElm)`.

Comment: @Titus, With `window.top.navigator...` and `"document_start"` the original object is not changed. And the injection work only with `"document_end"` but the page has already call the function before